# LibreOffice compares numbers incorrectly

Tags: libreoffice

Just see this screenshot. Why does it return TRUE instead of False? What is going wrong here?

[image]

Sanity check:

[image]

Comment: Those don't look like numbers... and they're very long, so they'll likely be rounded (as was indicated).  Store them as strings and they'll compare correctly.

Comment: @lornix they are numbers, I can substract and add them.